# Replace delay with millis

Tags: c++, arduino

I need to blink a LED for only 100 millisecond and the delay function in the loop make my code very unresponsive.

```
if (readString.indexOf("?23") >0){
  digitalWrite(23, LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(23, HIGH);
}
```

Is there a simple way to replace `delay` with `millis` to blink only once? I have tried this, but doesn't work

```
unsigned long interval1=1000;    // the time we need to wait
unsigned long previousMillis1=0; // millis() returns an unsigned long.

if (readString.indexOf("?22") >0){
  if ((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillis1) >= interval1) {
    previousMillis1 = millis();
    digitalWrite(22, LOW);
  }
  digitalWrite(22, HIGH);
```

Can you guys help me? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: can you edit and include the complete `loop()` function?

Comment: C++11's `std::condition_variable`s have methods to wait for a condition variable for a specified period of time, that can be specified in milliseconds.

Comment: Are you doing C or C++?

Comment: Thank you guys!  Jossef the loop has the same code but for 15 relays.

Comment: i uses C not C++

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good description of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that you are trying to turn on the LED for 100ms, when the string variable `readString` contains the defined literal string, and turning it of after it.

I think you are missing an `else` in your code, because without it the `digitalWrite(22, LOW)` to turn off the LED will be directly followed by the `digitalWrite(22, HIGH)`, which will turn the LED on again. And with executing `previousMillis1 = millis()` you let the LED blink continuously, not only once.
Try something like this:

```cpp
unsigned long interval1=100;    // the time we need to wait
unsigned long previousMillis1=0; // millis() returns an unsigned long.
boolean led_blinking = false;

void loop(){
    if (readString.indexOf("?22") >0 && !led_blinking){
        led_blinking = true;
        previousMillis1 = millis();
    }
    if (led_blinking && millis() - previousMillis1 <= interval1) {
        digitalWrite(22, HIGH);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(22, LOW);
        led_blinking = false;
        readString = ""; /* resetting the string variable to prevent
                            further blinking, until the variable is set
                            by another part of the code */
    }

    // Do other task of the main loop
}
```

Note that, depending on the time it takes to execute the rest of your main loop, the timing here is not exact. But if you only want to have a visual sign of your condition, this will be sufficient.
If you don't want to reset the string variable, you can use another boolean variable, which you can set at the time, when the string variable is set. But don't forget resetting it instead of the string variable.